# Array formula in excel suddenly not working... troubleshooting

Tags: arrays, excel, function, if-statement

I am currently using this array formula..

```
 {=LARGE(IF(('Data Input'!$L$3:$L$15000=$B10)*('Data Input'!$H$3:$H$15000>$C10),'Data Input'!$O$3:$O$15000,0),1)}
```

Where B10 is a text ID, like 658A and L:L is the column with the IDs.
   C10 is a date, with H:H being the column with dates.
   O:O being the column with the # value that I am retrieving.

This formula works fine with my purposes when used with ctrl,shift,enter

The problem arises when I try to use...

```
 {=IF('Data Input'!$L$3:$L$15000=$B10,1,0)}
```

It always returns a FALSE result, even though it works correctly in the first formula.

What is different about the second formula that changes the results?
This is very strange to me.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `IF` is only comaring the first value of the array that is returned, so only if the first comparison is true, will it return a true value.

Example to illustrate:
[image]
formula

Formula:
`{=IF(A1:A3=B2,1,0)}` will; return 0, unless cell A1 is changed to true. To change the result to have it return true if any of the values are true, you have to resort to a little trickery...

First, use `--` to change the True/False values to 1/0, then use `SUM` to add them together. as IF treats any non-zero result as true, this will result in `1` being returned when any comparison is true.

Working through our example with the new formula `{=IF(SUM(--(A1:A3=B2)),1,0)}` (still an array formula) we get the following steps in evaluation:

```
=IF(SUM(--(A1:A3=B2)),1,0)
=IF(SUM(--(A1:A3=2)),1,0)
=IF(SUM(--({1,2,2}=2)),1,0)
=IF(SUM(--({False,True,True})),1,0)
=IF(SUM(0,1,1),1,0)
=IF(2,1,0)
=1
```

Comment: It seems I have succumbed to a classic mistake on these forums... simplifying a question for the sake of clarity but actually changing the question. I am actually using the if statement to find a certain date relative to the ID. Example: =if('Data Input'!$L$3:$L$15000=$B10,C10+((large((datecolumn)-C10),1),0). I am looking for the most recent date for a certain ID. There may be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Your second formula is, itself, returning an array. You are only viewing the top left element in that return array - which happens to be FALSE.

Your first formula returns a scalar value; that is the difference.

If you want to sum the '1' values then your second formula could be amended to

```
{=SUM(IF('Data Input'!$L$3:$L$15000=$B10,1,0))}
```

which is also a scalar return.

Comment: I made the mistake of simplifying the questions for the sake of clarity. I am actually looking for the most recent date of a certain ID. So my goal formula looks more like this... =if('Data Input'!$L$3:$L$15000=$B10,C10+((large((datecolumn)-C10),1),0). There may be a better way to do this.